# getbodyclass IE Issue magento (IE not takking this class but in mozilla and chrome its working fine)

Tags: jquery, html, css, magento

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" dir="ltr">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?> class="background_art" 
<?php if($ruqest_uri !=$home_uri2 and $ruqest_uri !=$new_url and $ruqest_uri !=$new_uri ){ echo "style='background:none;'";  }?> <?php if($snv=="no"){ ?> onload="firsttimeload()" <?php } ?> >

 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is that this

```
<body <?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?> class="background_art" ....>
```

produces

You need to change it into

```
<body <?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?> class="background_art <?php echo $this->getBodyClass()? $this->getBodyClass() : ''; ?>" ...>
```

Then it will produce

```
<body class="background_art ..something.." ...>
```